# Python backup android application problem with decoding

Tags: android, backup

I'm writing a python script to make a Backup from an Android Application with adb:

`os.system("adb backup -apk -nosystem " + app_identifier)`

Than I m trying to parse the .ab file with python into tar so I can open it:

`os.system( "dd if=backup.ab bs=1 skip=24 | python -c \"import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(" + "zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))\" > backup.tar" )`

Sometimes this works and sometime I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Do you know why this error pops? As I said sometimes it works, sometime not.

Asked google, it shows me results for other context.

Reinstalled python, reconnected android phone, ran the command in console

Comment: Idk why I m getting this error. When I run my script outside of venv it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using python to pipe a command into a new python interpreter, consider reading the file into a `bytes` object. You can do this using the `open` function (make sure to set `mode="rb"` to avoid decoding errors). The error you are hitting is because stdin is opened in text mode, which expects all input to be valid text, but you're reading in non-text (tarball) data.

For example:

```py
with open("backup.ab", "rb") as input_file:
    input_data = input_file.read()
with open("backup.tar", "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(zlib.decompress(input_data))
```

You may find that your code is faster without using Python at all. For simple tasks like this, a simple shell script may be more suited (but less portable).